# Interpolation with specified knots interpolate.splrep — unexpected result

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I can't understand how `interpolate.splrep` function works. The simple code doesn't throw any errors but `interpolate.splev` returns unexpected result.

```
degree = 4;
arg = np.linspace(0, 2.0 * np.pi, 1000);
val = np.sin(arg);

m = arg.size - degree - 1;
step = (arg[-1] - arg[0]) / (m + 1);
knots = np.linspace(step, m * step, m);

f = interpolate.splrep(arg, val, k=degree, s=0, t=knots, per=0);

x = 0.123456;
print interpolate.splev(x, f) - np.sin(x);
```

This code prints `2.81341438303e+118`, but if I change parameter `per`, the code works pretty well:

```
...
f = interpolate.splrep(arg, val, k=degree, s=0, t=knots, per=1);
...
```

The result is `-1.80411241502e-16`.
Can you explain me that results? Isn't a bug?

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `per` switches periodic boundary conditions (pbc). It seems that the fit does not converge without pbc, but with pbc, it works. You can see that also when plotting data and spline fit result: it will diverge only at the borders, the rest of the data set is nicely fitted!

The [documentation of the function `interpolate.splrep`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splrep.html) tells that having an even degree in combination is not a good idea. You have `degree = 4`(even) and `s = 0`.

It seems you have very many knots defined! A B-spline is a piecewise fit. If you have a lot of knots, each spline function will only be valid for a very small fraction of points. you have 1000 abscissa points and 995 knots. The fewer points the spline has to be valid for, the more degrees of freedom remain for the function, so if you have to few points, the spline can be virtually anything...

changing the line `m = arg.size - degree - 1;` to `m = arg.size - degree - 20;` already yields

```
>>> print interpolate.splev(x, f) - np.sin(x);
3.08053624276e-10
```

without pbc!

So, ask yourself why you calculate the number of knots the way you do! Either you stick to it and introduce pbc, i.e. `per=1`, or you reduce the number of knots a bit. Both will stabilize the fit and enables convergence!

Comment: I understand what exactly I wrote and what each parameter means. This is not a random code, this is just simplified chunk of my program. 
The only thing I don't understand is why the routine does not throw any error if it can't process the input data. It's really strange behaviour and this may lead to serious problems in big projects.
If the routine can't process the input data correctly it must inform about that.

Comment: It doesn't have a problem in finding a solution, it's rather that you expect the fit to converge, which is not necessarily the case. Most numpy/scipy fit functions don't throw errors or warnings when not converging, you will always have to check some diagnosis data, e.g. Covariances... In case the number of knots is fix, is there a serious problem with pbc?

Comment: Do U thing it's not a problem? It's sad. MATLAB works much better in such cases. If u gonna solve a system of linear equations that is close to a singular MATLAB shows (at least) a warning. It really helps in debugging of big projects.

Comment: Some of those functions give 'rank warnings', but there are configurations where they don't. Now we are in a discussion which tends to go off-topic. To me it is unclear whether you want a fit that works or whether you complain about missing warnings. I have an answer for the former, the latter should be discussed in the scipy mailing list.